# How to add a List of a pair of integers as a value in a Map with key as first value in the pair - Java

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist, hashmap

I want to know how I achieve this scenario - I have a list of a Pair of integers (a,b) - for example

[[0, 3],[0,3],[0,4],[1,2],[1,8],[1,14],[2,4],[2,5],[2,6]] - List of type PairInt

```
The pairInt functionality is defined like this:

    class PairInt {
        int first, second;

        public PairInt(int first, int second) {
            this.first = first;
            this.second = second;
        }
    }
```

I want to add this Integer pair to a Map, such that it is organized like this:
{0: [3, 3, 4], 1: [2, 8, 14], 2: [4, 5, 6]}), that is for example the key 0 should have values associated with it and so on.

Suppose I have a HashMap that is declared like this:

```
 HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> dm = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();
```

This can be done in Python as simple as ,

```
mapd= defaultdict(list)
    for first, second in pairList:
        mapd[first].append(second)
        print(mapd)
```

That is iterate through the list and add it to the Map, such that it takes the above mentioned organization. How do I reproduce this behavior in Java for the HashMap structure mentioned above

Suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it.

Use `Collectors.groupingBy` to group by the first element of the pair. The value is the second element of the pair collected as a list.

```
dm = pairInts.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(pairInt -> pairInt.first, 
                    Collectors.mapping(pairInt -> pairInt.second, Collectors.toList())));
```

If you have *getters* in your `PairInt` class, you can write using method references as:

```
pairInts.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(PairInt::getFirst,
                    Collectors.mapping(PairInt::getSecond, Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest is to use a guava multimap (just add all pairs as key-value pairs). The map you want is some special view of it.